# How can I setup a Material in Cycles for Z-Transparency?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor, transparency

After converting to nodes in order to render using Cycles I've no idea where to enable the z-transparency. I guess the image textures alpha channel needs to be pluged somewhere but I've no idea which node would be suitable.

The question is how could I correctly setup the nodes to have the same effect as when using z-transparency in BI?

[image]
[image]

The materials original settings for BI are:

[image]

Which renders like:

[image]

I had no luck with DarenWs suggestion:

[image]

Comment: Remove the link of Image Texture Color to Transparent BSDF color, and set the transparent color to pure white.  (Looks like you figured it out, but for future reference.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a Mix shader as the last node before the Material Output.   feeding it the hair material (diffuse shader or whatever) in the lower input, a Transparency shader in the upper, and the image texture's alpha into the Mix's "fac" input.

[image: Example node setup]

Comment: Using a freshly-made PNG with transparency as the image texture, this does not work. I have duplicated these steps twice. I restarted Blender 2.75a and tried it a 3rd time. It does not work.

Comment: @user16716  You could [ask a new question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and provide some more details (screenshots, a [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) etc).

Comment: @DarenW, how to make the node connections like this?