# Make part of a texture transparent

Tags: image

[image: the nodes of the image]i need to add a logo to an intro. i have put the psd onto a plane but need to get rid of the white cube around the logo so that it is just the logo with no bg. how do i go about doing this? i am yet to try and solve this alone because i found nothing online to help me do it. I have added a pic of the logo i need to be cut out.[image: this is the logo]

Comment: Does it have an alpha channel?

Comment: what do you mean by that? i havent been using blender for so long

Comment: added picture of nodes.

Comment: Alpha channel is an extra channel in some image formats to store transparency,you can add an alpha channel is photoshop or any other photo editing software then use it in blender.

Comment: so i must edit the image outside of blender, i see.

Comment: You will just use the alpha output as a factor between your shaders and a transparent shader.

Comment: In Photoshop, since this is the software you're using, put your logo on a layer other than the Background, select all the areas that you need it to be transparent, which means everything except for the logo in your case, then delete it, hide the Background, you should be able to see the transparency grid in Photoshop "the grey checker", then go to file menu > Save for web and devices, choose PNG 24 with transparency enabled, and save your image, now in Blender you can use the Alpha in the Image Texture Node as a factor for Mix Shader.

Comment: Does the answer in this link answers your question?http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35127/how-to-make-transparent-material-in-cycles/35165#35165

Answer (score 4):

## Solution 1

If your image has alpha channel or you can create it¹, you can use it to mix your original shader with a transparent shader.

Your node setup adjusted:

[image: First solution]

¹Since you mentioned psd, I assume you use PhotoShop. Use the magic wand or (polygonal) lasso selector tool to: Select and delete what should be transparent; or add a mask and fill those parts of the mask with black. You may have to setup the image to enable the alpha channel.

## Solution 2

If your image has black background, and is only black where the logo should be transparent, you can use that as a condition for mixing your original shader with a transparent shader.

Your node setup adjusted:

[image]

You may use other values (between 0 and 1) in the *Greater than* node as the threshold for masking the darkest parts of the image. Also, you may use *Less then* node insted to mask white areas of the image (in case your background is white).