# How do I make a Minecraft character transparant?

Tags: transparency

I'm making an image for a person on YouTube and I need to know how to make one of the characters transparent as if he is in spectator mode.
I have tried multiple "make transparent" answers but they just made him either disappear or still posed as a solid object in render.
I have even tried making the skin itself more transparent but that didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to use the mix node? If so, mix the transparent shader with the diffuse shader

Comment: That has worked in making him transparent but when i switch to render view he becomes a solid object...is it because they are the wrong way around?

Comment: View my answer, is this the node set up that you created?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make transparent material in cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35127/how-to-make-transparent-material-in-cycles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick cycles transparency material:

[image: Transparent and diffuse shader]

Comment: after a little fiddling i realised its because of the black on the skin that is causing him to still look solid...after REALLY lowering the mix shader it has faded him enough for it to pass off as being in creative...thanks