# How to add a image with alpha channel over a material?

Tags: texturing

I have a cube that have the original Blender material (diffuse BSDF, color is white), and I want to add a icon on it

The problem is I added a .png image onto the box, but then the face become black, and that really confuses me

I am a noob to 3d modeling, so please advise, sorry for my bad English..

Comment: Please edit your question and add some more information like how you set up your material, how it looks when you render, and possibly screenshots of your material settings and node setup.

Comment: For starters [have you unwrapped your cube](https://www.google.com/search?&tbm=vid&q=blender+unwrap+beginner)? To use image textures you have to unwrap the mesh first. Also, if you image is a PNG with transparent background you [have to tell Blender what to put "behind it"](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6416/transparent-image-textures-in-cycles) in the transparent areas.

Comment: If you are using cycles please read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15207/setup-a-decal-material-in-cycles or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447

Comment: Thanks cegaton and Duarte Farrajota Ramos ,Helped me a lot , now my problem solved thanks!!!