# Transparent PNG over a base material

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to have a transparent PNG over a base material.

I tried using the same technique as mentioned here but somehow i am getting the mesh lines in the render.

[How can I setup a Material in Cycles for Z-Transparency?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/how-can-i-setup-a-material-in-cycles-for-z-transparency)

[Transparent image textures in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6416/transparent-image-textures-in-cycles)

Can someone please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Regards S

Comment: Did you exported UV Map to external software? It seams like you didn't remove UV Map wires.

Comment: @LukeD Yes. Sorry i did not notice that the texture had the UV wires on them. Thank you.

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447