# How do I make a mesh transparent but the texture shows up in render

Tags: mesh, texturing

I was wondering if I could have a mesh that's invisible but I can still see the texture.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by that, it's not clear what you are asking? Maybe post some reference pictures, and what render engine you plan to use.

Comment: Im using blender render. I have a mesh. It has a texture. I need to make the mesh transparent. And the texture show

Comment: can you please make either an image of what you want or clarify what you mean by mesh and texture, because at least I seem to missunderstand you. AND edit your answer!

Comment: If you can see texture of the mesh it isn't transparent. If it is transparent you can't see texture of the mesh. However this might depend on texture - if e.g. *guessing* that you want to get something like leaves with leaf texture then the texture should have alpha channel and use Transparent shader, related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6416/transparent-image-textures-in-cycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood this correctly, you want to make your mesh invisible, but show up the texture put on it, right? So you need a texture that's not filling the entire mesh (like a leaf). You need a .png file with transparent background, otherwise it won't work. IF you mean this, have a look at this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gi3oFolsPI0

Edit: Or have a look at the idea given by Mr Zak if you don't want to watch the video (Cycles).