# How do you import an image with a transparent background?

Tags: animation, 2d

Seems basic and straight forward right?

Import a picture from a domain where you intentionally made the backgound transparent to find it with a clear white background once opened up in Blender.

My question: How... in 2.8, do you import a picture namely of LinArt with a transparent background or with, and then remove that background the picture most likely has been stuck onto once its opened in blender 2.8 to originally be left with literally just the lineart?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6416/transparent-image-textures-in-cycles/6423#6423 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/how-can-i-setup-a-material-in-cycles-for-z-transparency

Comment: Read also: [image alpha when using images as planes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27633/image-alpha-background-renders-black-when-using-import-images-as-planes/27635#27635)