# transparent PNG image not working in cycles

Tags: transparency

[image]

Hello blender community.
using Blender2.79b
I am working on creating leaf with PNG transparent image file.
but alpha part is not working as transparent part.
My node setup is wrong ? or any other cause?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6416/transparent-image-textures-in-cycles/6423?r=SearchResults#6423

Comment: Duplicate of [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46447/1853)

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the transparency node, but the translucency node

Transparency makes the area transparent while translucency let's some light throu but scatters it a little bit. A good example for this are the leaves on trees. If the sun shines on them, they are bright from both sides, while the trunk is only bright on one side, as it is not letting light pass throu

Comment: thanks for the great answer. I really appreciate.

Comment: If it was the rigth one you can mark it as the correct answer :)