# Animating animated 2D Sprites

Tags: animation, texturing, 2d

I'm pretty new to Blender but wish to use it for an animated project. Now, the animation itself will be pretty simple after I figure out how to pull off this one effect, but first I need to see if it can pan out.

What I want basically is to animate with Animated 2D Sprites that swerve about in a 3D setting, akin to something like the Nintendo video game Paper Mario or the YouTube series Petscop.
Here is an example of an animated sprite:
[image: Sprite example.]

I would want to be able to alternate between sprites for a few characters, but really, that is the length of what I need to know. Any way to pull this off that isn't excruciating? Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you wanna mix 2d with 3d? what did you try? did you check "grease pencil"?

Comment: Not even sure what grease pencil is. Basically what I want is to be able to have objects that are merely sprite textures, like planes to move about but with an animated texture on top.

Comment: does this help?https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/animating-eye-texture-in-a-head-mesh

Comment: Would that work with image transparency? Again, I'm very new.

Comment: yep: check this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6416/transparent-image-textures-in-cycles/6423#6423

Comment: Thanks so much for all the references. It seems like a LOT of work with a sprite with this many frames, but if it's the only way...

Comment: Try the grease pencil (use google or your favorite search engine). It will give you the flexibility you are after.

Comment: Hmm I'll look into it.. this functions with imported images such as .gifs?