# Only show colour and NOT transparency?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I have a hair texture , and i took away the white background , but the white hasn't gone away yet!? I want it so all the white is gone and it only shows the colours on the texture .

[image: Clearly transparent texture showing white]

![Added][3]

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I setup a Material in Cycles for Z-Transparency?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/how-can-i-setup-a-material-in-cycles-for-z-transparency)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are generally four steps to make sure the viewport alpha display:

- Set **Transparency** Alpha value to `0.000` in Material setting;
- Toggle **Alpha** influence in Texture setting;
- Switch to **GLSL** shading mode in 3D View Property panel;
- Use **Texture** as viewport shading type.

[image]

Besides, make sure **Using Alpha** is toggled in Texture panel, although it's set as default. And you may want to use **UV** as the coordinate type of texture mapping for most of the case.

---

However, it is interesting that you can even preview it without assigning any material, even in the default **Multitexture** shading mode (just like when you drag and drop an local image onto a object in the scene). And of course, it cannot be rendered, since no material assigned.

[image]

Comment: Wow!!! you have got my attention , it DOES work , but in the render image some of it turns out like this?? ( i added a new picture )

Comment: I really wonder your settings for materal and texture. Would you also paste the screenshot for that? or we can go to the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm) now :) (I'm in the one called Renderfarm).

Comment: ill post a picture now :)

Comment: You don't need to toggle off the color influence, in this case. So, toggle both Color and Alpha, as shown in my picture.

Comment: Ok i have it working  now :) Thank you very much