# Transparency problem with texture using cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, transparency

I am trying to use a basic plane and texturing it with a doily for a table. The doily texture has an alpha layer. I used a mix shader with a transparency shader and the diffuse image shader and the factor from the image itself. I got a really weird result (picture below).

[image]

I tried using black for the color of the transparency and it ended up with this:
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I setup a Material in Cycles for Z-Transparency?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/how-can-i-setup-a-material-in-cycles-for-z-transparency)

Comment: I don't consider it a duplicate because the OP tried the technique used in the other post, but had trouble with it. This question adds information about problems that someone might encounter when using that technique.

Comment: @Matt The answer on that question states quite clearly that the transparent node should go into the upper slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured it out. I need to switch the order of the textures in the mix node. Whoops.

[image]