# Cycles not using transparency in decal texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, transparency

I'm trying to apply the logo onto the glossy part and cycles render ignores the transparency and just makes it black.

[image]

I've tried both png and tga using the multiple builds of blender. And it looks weird in texture mode even though the uv map shows transparency.

[image]

**[Blendfile](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ppizp0bsawsp5za/keyboard3.blend)**

Comment: Weird. Can you share the .blend file? You may have misconfigured something...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I setup a Material in Cycles for Z-Transparency?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/how-can-i-setup-a-material-in-cycles-for-z-transparency)

Comment: File: http://www.mediafire.com/download/ppizp0bsawsp5za/keyboard3.blend

Answer (score 1):

- In fact, the transparency of that logo wasn't ignored. The reason why the logo's background shows black is that you just see though it, and there's little light and nothing behind (inside the keyboard, actually).
- In this case, all you need to do is simply mix it with a node group containing the same node setup as the keyboard material (the one located in the first material slot):

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Did some stuff with nodes thanks to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lw-YHoxpAnk#

[image]