# Transparency is showing up white on UV mapping

Tags: uv, transparency

As you can see by the screen shot my label has transparency that's instead showing up white when I uvwrap the label on the bottle. I know it has to be something simple but there's no option to make it recognize transparency (like when bringing in an image to the modeling window I can select alpha transparency).

[image]

Comment: Seems to me like you've been asking the same question several times. The trick is very simple: In Cycles when you use images with alpha channel on nodes, the transparency is not used automagically. You need to connect the alpha channel of the image to something. Most of the time is to a mix node (either an RGB mix or a shader) to control how images or shaders are mixed. Look at the previous answers to your questions and pay particular attention to how the alpha socket is being connected to other nodes.

Comment: see also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40901/setup-for-a-wine-bottle-with-multiple-labels and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9261/cycles-not-using-transparency-in-decal-texture

Comment: Yeah.. it seems to me there's more than one way to make things transparent.. and every time I attempt another label all these nodes get jumbled in my head and I know I am not understanding.. but I'm trying the best I can. I'm sorry.