# Rendered image has black outlines from imported image

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, image

Second day of using Blender, I was trying to make a flower but the rendered object has a black base from the image outline. Here is the before and after image.  Any suggestions?
[image: before rendering]

[image: after rendering]

Comment: Sorry for the wrong flag, the answer is in the node setup here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/9268/30849. Look at the mix of node which uses the alpha channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the number of transparent bounces in render tab

[image]