# Limit rendering to a specific part of the world

Tags: rendering, scripting

My blender file represents one object for an isometric tiled game. I now want to render this object in multiple parts according to my coordinate system.

What I need is to tell blender it should only render inside of a specific cube-sized area (parallel to Blender's global axes).

- I tried adding a cube mesh in combination with Boolean modifier. Did not work as expected.
- Is there a way I can set a minXYZ/maxXYZ option for rendering?
- Another option I'm not seeing right now?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8600/599

Comment: @gandalf3 Solidify+Boolean: Either it works wrong or shows "Cannot execute boolean operation" and doesn't work at all. Nodes: I'm not using cycles so I don't have the needed node types available. Even if I switch to cycles then it seems I have to edit all materials I am using.

Comment: If your using BI you can still take the same approach, and use a texture to define what parts of the model should/should not be transparent. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1842/599