# Semi-transparent lightning image rendering incorrectly

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image: Lightning and node setup]

Hi, not sure what to do, I have spent days on this. I am trying to get the image to appear as lightning, not just a blob.

The left image is what I what to show up, and the right image is what renders.

Comment: Never mind. LOL. I figured it out, literally 9 seconds after I posted this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I setup a Material in Cycles for Z-Transparency?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/how-can-i-setup-a-material-in-cycles-for-z-transparency)

Comment: What was your solution? Or does the linked question in the comment above help?

Comment: how did you figure that out? ive been trying to figure this out for awile now

Answer (score 2):

Your *Less Than* node is looking for values *below* `.9`, and so is picking up the subtle glare around the lighting in your image.

Perhaps you meant to set it to *Greater Than*?