# Blender 2.8 Leaf Transparency Issue, with Eevee

Tags: modeling, transparency

Somehow i'm not being able to pull this off.    I've tried searching on google for solutions but couldn't find it.   I thought the setup was quite simple, but it don't seem to work properly.

If you take a look at the image below you'll see what i mean.

I've tried changing the Blend Mode on the Settings TAB, i've enabled screen space refraction...

It seems that i'm missing out on something.     Any thoughts ?   Thank you

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1842/how-can-i-setup-a-material-in-cycles-for-z-transparency

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) 2 reasons why they are not transparent:

- your leaf texture is a *.jpg* file: this format can't carry transparency informations. Only *.png* images can have a transparent background in the image itself.
- You are connecting the *Color* output of the **Image Texture** node into the *Fac* of the **Mix Shader**, but the latter needs a black and white image, where black means transparent and white means opaque. You should use the *Alpha* output instead, which takes the transparency of your *.png* texture and transforms it into a BW map for the **Mix Shader**